# Optimizing the below PgSQL query, though it serves the purpose but is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

Here I wanna retrieve the count of ID which has been already existing in the table. For example, I pull a record for 15 mins, so I would like to get the ID that already exists in the table and is not unique.

```
select count(*)
from "XYZ" a
where "StationName" in ('St_1','St_2') 
and "DateTime" between '2021-04-30 09:00:00.000' and '2021-05-03 09:15:59.999'
and "ID" in (select "ID" from "XYZ" b
                   where "StationName" in ('St_1','St_2')
                   and b."DateTime" < a."DateTime"
                  );
```

Comment: Please describe what you want the query to do.

Comment: also provide execution pan including buffers

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff, for formating the above code, here I wanna retrieve the count of ID which has been already existing in the table. 

For example, I pull a record for 15 mins, so I would like to get the ID that already exists in the table and is not unique.

Comment: What if you just remove the superfluous final condition with the subquery and add an index on `"DateTime"`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to count all the "St_1" and "St_2" stations on each `id` that occur before the last one.  If so, I would suggest using window functions:

```
select count(*)
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from "XYZ" a
      where "StationName" in ('St_1', 'St_2') 
     ) a
where "DateTime" between '2021-04-30 09:00:00.000' and '2021-05-03 09:15:59.999' and
      seqnum > 1;
```

For this, I would recommend an index on `(stationName, id, datetime)`.